# Parsing images with Jsoup bou returned null

Tags: android-studio, web-scraping, jsoup, html-parsing

I'm studying about `Jsoup` and developing my own app showing some events.

I want to parse this [Home Page](http://event.lottecinema.co.kr/LCHS/Contents/Event/event-summary-list.aspx)

And I want to parse [This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxpdF.png)

So, I wrote code like this.

```
private String url = "http://event.lottecinema.co.kr/LCHS/Contents/Event/event-summary-list.aspx";
...
Elements imgs = document.select("html body form#form1 div#wrap div#container.sub div#content div.event_Hwrap.allevPg ul#emovie_list_20.emvie_list li a " );
...
 for(Element img : imgs) {
        imageTitles.add(img.attr("alt")); //event title list }
```

But there are not any images...
I don't know why.. because I parsed some images other Google sites.

Comment: Tried to open the link you gave - got timeout.

Comment: not able to read url, But in my point of issue is on the selector you select imgs from document . try it in  https://try.jsoup.org/

Comment: @TDG Thanks for your answer. I don't know why you can't open that url. But I checked I can open.

Comment: @ShankaraNethranS.N , Thanks for your answer, too! I opened my url and fetch that with your site... "try.jsoup.org" But I coudn't fetch that...TT So.. I can't use selector...

Answer (score 0):

you may try this selector

```
  Elements imgs = document.select("body img");
   for(Element img : imgs) 
    {
    String imgalt_attrval = img.attr("alt");
    String imgsrc_attrval = img.attr("src")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!
I tried with your codes.. But I can't see any change and returned null...